# Manage badges for push notification in iOS app (Phonegap)

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am building a phonegap based app and trying to update and manage the push notification badge in it. At this point of time, what I have checked all over SO the solution seems to be in either passing the value in 'aps' payload in our server code or in one of the methods that we have in AppDelegate.(I have done this both and found it to be working)
However, what I want to know is to how to keep a real time update of the number of notifications received/read by the user so as to update the app icon automatically?
I believe it is related to our server code, but I would really appreciate a detailed example/explanation on how to get this done as I have been struggling to get this work for a full week now.
P.S: I have checked almost all the links related to badge in iOS in Stack Overflow but have not found something with enough code or example to get this working successfully.
Thanks.